# Выравнивание заголовка в один ряд с навигационными ссылками

Tags: html, css

Верстаю макет, и столкнулся с проблемой выравнивания `<span class="caption"><sup>El</sup>Artista</span>` в один ряд с навигационными ссылками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ни старался, не получается. Надеюсь на вашу помощь! Заранее благодарю.

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
  background: url("../images/header-img.png") no-repeat center top/cover;
  height: 700px;
}

.header .caption {
  color: #bb1b55;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: "SCRIPTIN";
}

.header .menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 41%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
}

.header .menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.header .menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header .container {
  margin: 150px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.header .container h1 {
  font-family: "SCRIPTIN";
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #bb1b55;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.header .btn {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(55deg, #f75644 1%, #a0015d 99%);
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Idea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Crew</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Showreel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <span class="caption"><sup>El</sup>Artista</span>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="big-caption">Catching the spirit</h1>
  </div>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Contact us</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Какой версии bootstrap сетку Вы используете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Позиционирование](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

`static` - дефолтное значение. Один блок идёт под другим в порядке их появления в хтмл, за исключением не блочных элементов, таких как `span`.

`relative`: если просто его установить, то ничего не поменяется. Но если дать ему значения `top` или `left`, то блок сдвинется.

`absolute`: если блок, который мы так позиционируем, находится в неспозионированном блоке, (то есть, который имеет позиционирование `static`), то позиционирование будет происходить относительно боди, кажется. Но если мы дадим родительскому компоненту какое-то НЕ ДЕФОЛТНОЕ позиционирование, то абсолют будет позиционироваться относительно родительского объекта.

`fixed, sticky` разбирать вообще не стоит. Там и так всё понятно.

Как я вижу, ваш хедер не спозиционирован никак. Надо дать ему позиционирование `relative`, а спану назначить `display: block; position: absolute; top: XXpx; left: XXpx`, и, по идее, это должно вылечить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Пример в полноэкранном режиме смотрите.
Добавил в `nav` ваш спан с логотипом и задал `flex` для `nav`.

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
  background: url("../images/header-img.png") no-repeat center top/cover;
  height: 700px;
}
.header nav {
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.header .caption {
  color: #bb1b55;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: "SCRIPTIN";
  
}

.header .menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
}

.header .menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.header .menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.header .container {
  margin: 150px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.header .container h1 {
  font-family: "SCRIPTIN";
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #bb1b55;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.header .btn {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(55deg, #f75644 1%, #a0015d 99%);
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav>
    <span class="caption"><sup>El</sup>Artista</span>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Idea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Crew</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Showreel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="big-caption">Catching the spirit</h1>
  </div>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Contact us</a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

К примеру если разделить на части логотип то есть сделать одну часть родительским то вторую часть мы сможем поставить абсолютно.

Посмотреть на мои тренировки то как делал это можно: [здесь](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oRjgba?editors=1000)

Выглядеть это будет как в снипете ..чуть чуть адаптировал даже

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.menu .item p{
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  font-size:90px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.menu .item p span{
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:20px;
}
.menu{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  line-height:20px;
  height:100px;
}

.menu a{
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left:6px;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
  .menu{
    display:flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height:150px;
    margin-top:40px;
  }
  .menu .item a{
    display:block;
  }
  .mnav{
    display:none;
  }
  span.trigger{
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  span.trigger i{
    display:block;
    width:70%;
    height:6px;
    margin-top:4px;
    background:#000;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="menu">
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      el
      <span>artista</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="trigger">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </span>
    <div class="mnav">
      <a href=""><a href="">item1</a></a>
      <a href=""><a href="">item2</a></a>
      <a href=""><a href="">item3</a></a>
      <a href=""><a href="">item4</a></a>
      <a href=""><a href="">item5</a></a>
      <a href=""><a href="">item6</a></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```